# Need to get resize function to work immediately

Tags: jquery, fonts, resize

I have made a quick function that will proportionally resize my text when the window resizes but I need it to detect the size when it loads too. I am new to jQuery and think I am missing something really simple here.

https://jsfiddle.net/ctyapt2h/

```
$('.smash').each(function () {

    var font = $(this),
        maxFont = parseFloat(font.css('font-size')), 
        minFont = '16px';

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

        var curWid = $(window).width(),
            ratio = (curWid / 1920),
            newFont = (maxFont * ratio);

        if (curWid <= 320) {
            font.css('font-size', minFont);
        } else {
            font.css('font-size', newFont + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manually trigger jQuery's .resize() method on document ready:

```
$('.smash').each(function () {

    var font = $(this),
        maxFont = parseFloat(font.css('font-size')), 
        minFont = '16px';

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

        var curWid = $(window).width(),
            ratio = (curWid / 1920),
            newFont = (maxFont * ratio);

        if (curWid <= 320) {
            font.css('font-size', minFont);
        } else {
            font.css('font-size', newFont + 'px');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

create function to resize, and call it when page load.

```
$('.smash').each(function () {

    var font = $(this),
        maxFont = parseFloat(font.css('font-size')), 
        minFont = '16px';

     resizeME = function() {

        var curWid = $(window).width(),
            ratio = (curWid / 1920),
            newFont = (maxFont * ratio);

        if (curWid <= 320) {
            font.css('font-size', minFont);
        } else {
            font.css('font-size', newFont + 'px');
        }
    };
    $(window).on('resize', resizeME());
    resizeME ();
});
```